# CREATE SNAPSHOT Creates Table Instead, Why?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

This reference states that you can use the command `CREATE SNAPSHOT TABLE` to create a snapshot: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-snapshots-create#sql_1

Yet when I use it in this form, [modified from this example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-snapshots-scheduled):

```
CREATE SNAPSHOT TABLE backup.facebook_video_metadata_20220601
CLONE redacted.data.facebook_video_metadata
OPTIONS(expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP '2022-06-08 19:50:02.948885+00')
```

...a **partitioned table**, *not* a **snapshot**, is created. Why?

Maybe my concern is that the logo does not match the other snapshot logos in the BigQuery Explorer:

[image: ace-icon-table-sharded] ace-icon-table-sharded -- this is the table created from `CREATE SNAPSHOT TABLE`

[image: ace-icon-snapshot] ace-icon-snapshot -- this is the snapshot created by using the snapshot button in the UI.

Comment: I tried your query and it created a [snapshot of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD3H5.png). AFAIK a snapshot is just a read only table. Can you share a screenshot of your snapshot details?

Comment: Looks like a simple UI bug. Reload/refresh page and you will get same/proper icons for both cases

Comment: I created a public issue tracker to report this UI bug. This could be tracked [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/235542609).

Comment: Refreshing the page did not load the correct icons for me. If it's just an icon issue, that really threw me for a loop haha